# vb.net class MustInherit Interface

Tags: vb.net, interface, abstract

I'm working in VB.Net.

I have several `X` objects.  Every one of them needs to have the `Y` function, so I need to choose `Interface` or `MustInherit`.  I also need to have a `Z` function exactly the same for each object.  This function is used only by the object's abstracted/implemented methods, like a printout for that kind of object.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd only use an interface if you expect there to be classes that implement `Y` but do not require the `Z` function.

I'd go with abstraction given all subclasses require the `Z` function.  If `Z` is only going to be used within the class, mark it as `Protected` so it's only visible to subclasses.

```
MustInherit Class BaseX
    Public MustOverride Sub Y();

    Protected Sub Z()
        ' TODO: Implement common version of Z.
    End Sub
End Class

Class FirstX Inherits BaseX
    Public Overrides Sub Y()
        ' TODO: Implement first version of Y.
        ' Call Z() as required.
    End Sub
End Class

Class SecondX Inherits MyBaseClass
    Public Overrides Sub Y()
        ' TODO: Implement second version of Y.
        ' Call Z() as required.
    End Sub
End Class
```

**NOTE:** I hope my VB is correct.  I don't have it installed so I can't validate my syntax.

Comment: I will check, but the overall seems good. seem answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't really understand your question. If you want a good answer, you may want to make your question more clear.
From what I understand, you want to know how to use inheritance to create two+ objects which inherit the same MustInherit class and perform similar actions with different implementations.
I don't understand the difference between your X function and Z function.

```
Public MustInherit Class theBase
    Public MustOverride Sub ZPrint()
End Class

Public Class a
    Inherits theBase
    Public Overrides Sub ZPrint()
        ' the "a" way to print
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class b
    Inherits theBase
    Public Overrides Sub ZPrint()
        ' the "b" way to print
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class theClass
    Public Sub run()
        Dim myA As theBase
        Dim myB As theBase
        myA = New a
        myB = New b
        myA.ZPrint()
        myB.ZPrint()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Make an instance of theClass and execute the run() method.

Comment: Z function is a "common" function between each class that inherits base class. Z shouldn't be overrides each time.

Comment: I understand the question better after seeing Hand-E-Food's answer. Kudos to him for comprehension.